# background execution is not working when receive push notification in ios

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, background

i am trying to data to core data when app receives push notification, this is working fine when app is in for-ground with below method

```
 func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
    {
        if let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo as? [String : Any]
        {
            let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? NSDictionary
            let alert = aps?["alert"] as? NSDictionary

                let context = self.persistentContainer.viewContext

                let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "NotificationDetails", in: context)
                let NotificationDetail = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)
                NotificationDetail.setValue( incidentDetails.incidentNumber, forKey: "Number")

                do {
                    try context.save()
                } catch {
                    print("Failed saving")
                }
         }
        }
```

But when the app is not working i am using below method , it is not saving,

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
    {
        if let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo as? [String : Any]
        {
            let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? NSDictionary
            let alert = aps?["alert"] as? NSDictionary

                let context = self.persistentContainer.viewContext

                let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "NotificationDetails", in: context)
                let NotificationDetail = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)
                NotificationDetail.setValue( incidentDetails.incidentNumber, forKey: "Number")

                do {
                    try context.save()
                } catch {
                    print("Failed saving")
                }
         }


        completionHandler(.newData)
    }
```

How can i save data when app in not working?

Comment: you can implement silent push notification but it has some limitations. You need to explore more about it whether it is useful or not

Comment: Check you check if this method gets called -    private func userNotificationCenter(center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceiveNotificationResponse response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: () -> Void)

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that your notification payload has "content-available":1; something like :

```
{
   "aps" : {
      "content-available" : 1
   },
   "acme1" : "bar",
   "acme2" : 42
}
```

And then, you will get a callback in :

```
application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)
```

Comment: Do go through this : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app

Comment: i already enabled the capability, still not working  i am getting like below is this currect?

alert =     {
        body = "Message body";
        title = "title";
    };
    "content-available" = 1;
    "mutable-content" = 1;
}]